# Problems getting an assembly code from gcc - did my best

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I'm working under linux, and having some problems while trying to create a MIPS assembly file from my *.c code.

All I'm getting is a *.s file with a code that looks like this (for example):

```
    .file   "1.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Please enter your string: \n"
.LC1:
    .string "Please enter char to find: "
.LC2:
    .string "The char %c appears %d times\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $160, %esp
    movl    %gs:20, %eax
    movl    %eax, 156(%esp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $0, 16(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    puts
    movl    stdin, %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    $128, 4(%esp)
    leal    28(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    fgets
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    call    getchar
    movb    %al, 27(%esp)
    movl    $0, 20(%esp)
    jmp .L2
.L4:
    movl    20(%esp), %eax
    movzbl  28(%esp,%eax), %eax
    cmpb    27(%esp), %al
    jne .L3
    addl    $1, 16(%esp)
.L3:
    addl    $1, 20(%esp)
.L2:
    movl    20(%esp), %eax
    movzbl  28(%esp,%eax), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L4
    movsbl  27(%esp),%edx
    movl    $.LC2, %eax
    movl    16(%esp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, 8(%esp)
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    156(%esp), %edx
    xorl    %gs:20, %edx
    je  .L6
    call    __stack_chk_fail
.L6:
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu8) 4.4.1"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

All i did was writing gcc -S 1.c and the file been created.. BUT i need it to be a MIPS code not a 808x assembly code... what shall i do ?
I did my best to understand the mystery of cross compilers, but nothing.... i didn't understood anything...

If someone that do hold that cross compiler can do it for me for the following 2 codes, I will be more than happy...

**The first code is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 128

int main ()

{
    char mychar , string [SIZE];
    int i;
    int count =0 ;  

    printf ("Please enter your string: \n\n");
    fgets (string, SIZE, stdin);

    printf ("Please enter char to find: ");
    mychar = getchar();

    for (i=0 ; string[i] != '\0' ; i++ )
        if ( string[i]  == mychar )
            count++;

    printf ("The char %c appears %d times\n" ,mychar ,count);


    return 0;
}
```

**And the second code is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[]);

int main ()
{
    int x[20] = {0} , y[20] = {0};
    int m=0,temp=0,curr=0,i=0,j=0;

    printf("Please enter your numbers now:\n\n");

    /*enter numbers one by one. if x[i+1] value < x[i] value, err msg.
      when user want to end the series he must enter '0' which means end of string (it wont       included in x[]) */
    while ( (scanf("%d",&temp) ) != 5 )
    {
        if (temp >= curr)
        {
            x[i] = temp;
            curr = temp;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The numbers are not at the right order !\n\nProgram will now terminate...\n\n");
        }
    }

    SIFT(x,y);

    for (i=0 ; y[i]=='0' ; i++) /*strlen(y) without ('0')'s includes*/
        m++;

    /*Prints  m , y's organs*/
    printf("\n\nm = %d",m);
    printf("Y = ");
    while (y[j]!='0')
    {
        printf ("%d ,",y[j]);
        j++;
    }

return 0;
}

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    while (x_arr[i] != '0')
    {
        if (x_arr[i] == x_arr[i+1]) /*if current val. equals next val. -> jump dbl at x_arr*/
        {
            y_arr[j] = x_arr[i];
            i+=2;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            y_arr[j]=x_arr[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }    

}
```

I really do appreciate all efforts !

Comment: If you're doing this for a MIPS class at school, you're going to be disappointed to find out that GCC may not necessarily now how to translate functions like printf according to how your professor may want you to. When I took a MIPS class, the prof wanted printf calls to be translated to syscalls, whereas GCC is likely to just insert a call to printf.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a build of GCC that generates MIPS code?  It looks like you're passing your code to an x86 compiler!  A list of GCC options for MIPS can be found in the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Options.html).  If those don't work, you're going to need to build yourself a compiler that does work with MIPS.  Some pre-built Linux options and instructions to build your own can be found at the [LinuxMIPS wiki](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains).

Comment: I don't think I have one, but I tried all of those manuals and they only confused me with a long and complicated explanations...

Comment: @C_guy - if you don't have a MIPS compiler, you're not going to get MIPS code.  That's about all there is to it.

Comment: I tried:
> gcc -mips1 1.c and I got "unrecognized command line". but when I did: > gcc -march= 1.c I got "missing argument to -march=". what seems to be the solution\problem ?

Comment: @C_guy - go download and/or build yourself a MIPS toolchain.

Comment: And i need a little or a big endian ?

Comment: @C_guy, I have no idea - what hardware do you have?

Comment: The linux is running under VMWorkstation under Win7 OS under P4_S800D

Comment: @C_guy, not the hardware you're *compiling* on, the hardware the MIPS code needs to *run* on.  You need to build a compiler that matches endianness of the machine you intend to *run* the resulting code on.

Comment: Ho.. this is for academic purpose not for real hardware, I'm just passing the code to SPIM simulator, I don't know if it simulate little endian or big endian....

Comment: little endian.... so if i want the easiest way to convert my code, i need to download the cross toolchain for little endian ?

Comment: @C_guy - you're on your own now, sorry.  If you can't figure out how to follow the very clear instructions at the wiki link I posted in my original answer, I certainly can't help you in these comments.  Good luck.

Comment: Can you only post those two codes in MIPS ? I just need it once, I don't need to convert C codes permanently... please...?

Comment: @C_guy, I don't have a MIPS cross-compiler, and I'm certainly not going to go get one and do it for you when you have all the tools to do it yourself.

Comment: Is there a better \simple way to do it under WIN OS ? because I need those codes really urgent...

Comment: I can't believe I'm really going to reply here again.  @C_guy - you can get windows cross compilers, too, yes.  It's up to you if that's "simpler" or not, though.